# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain while using the following code in Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

String cognitoIdentityId = sp.getString("aws_identity", "");
                String openIdToken = sp.getString("aws_token", "");

```
            Map<String,String> logins = new HashMap<>();
            logins.put("cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", openIdToken);
            GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest getCredentialsRequest =
                    new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest()
                            .withIdentityId(cognitoIdentityId)
                            .withLogins(logins);
            AmazonCognitoIdentityClient cognitoIdentityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient();
            GetCredentialsForIdentityResult getCredentialsResult = cognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(getCredentialsRequest);
            Credentials credentials = getCredentialsResult.getCredentials();
            AWSSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                    credentials.getAccessKeyId(),
                    credentials.getSecretKey(),
                    credentials.getSessionToken()
            );
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: "Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain" is the exact exception @JuanSebastian

Comment: do you get which one is the offending line? i suspect you dont have a valid access key id and secret key loading into your code so you can access aws resources.

Answer (score 0):

The error was with the syntax
Correct code is

```
cognitoIdentityId = sp.getString("aws_identity", "");
            String openIdToken = sp.getString("aws_token", "");

            Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
            logins.put("cognito-identity.amazonaws.com", openIdToken);
            GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest getCredentialsRequest =
                    new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest()
                            .withIdentityId(cognitoIdentityId)
                            .withLogins(logins);
            AmazonCognitoIdentityClient cognitoIdentityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials());
            GetCredentialsForIdentityResult getCredentialsResult = cognitoIdentityClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(getCredentialsRequest);
            Credentials credentials = getCredentialsResult.getCredentials();
            AWSSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                    credentials.getAccessKeyId(),
                    credentials.getSecretKey(),
                    credentials.getSessionToken()
            );

            AWS_KEY = sessionCredentials.getAWSAccessKeyId();
            AWS_SECRET = sessionCredentials.getAWSSecretKey();
            AWS_SESSION = sessionCredentials.getSessionToken();
```